# AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'noun_chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I'm trying to use spacy `noun_chunks` but it's throwing an error.
I downloaded the model with 
`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

`AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'noun_chunks'`

```
NLP = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
NOUN_CHUNKS = NLP.noun_chunks
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How did you come up with that code? The loaded `nlp` processing object doesn't have a property `noun_chunks` – instead, you want to be accessing the noun chunks of a **processed document**:

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  # load the English model
doc = nlp("There is a big dog.")    # process a text and create a Doc object
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:       # iterate over the noun chunks in the Doc
   print(chunk.text)
# 'a big dog'
```

For more details, see [the documentation here](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#noun-chunks).